# Select box disable while edit using jquery and send post value in disadbled field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some value in edit form and i need to disable select box, In edit and click update the form need to update record and select box disable or readonly and send the post value , i have used

```
$("#user_name").prop( "disabled", true);
```

in this way field form field get disable and can't change or edit value but the problem is i can't get post value for update record, Thanks for your answer

Comment: Show us some code so we get an idea what you are talking about.

Comment: If the field is disabled then form element `value` will not be posted. Use `readonly`

Comment: i am wondering why would you want the data in post when the user cannot edit it?

Comment: edit case selected value fetch in the field and that value need to send as post data , in disabled case post data is not sending... i try readonly instead of disabled but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

As you are well aware of the face that a `SELECT` does not have `READONLY` attribute. Please use this with your `SELECT` tag.

```
<select id="user_name" onfocus="this.defaultIndex=this.selectedIndex;" onchange="this.selectedIndex=this.defaultIndex;">
```

And you won't be needing

```
$("#user_name").prop( "disabled", true);
```

**OR**

You can use this.

```
<select id="user_name">
<option disabled="disabled">1</option>
<option selected="selected">2</option>
<option disabled="disabled">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer actually i need to disable when edit action occur, edit case only certain case only get edit, this select field get visible as disabled and need to send value inside edit form field, this way the post value is set as empty

Comment: You can pass a flag or you can also use a hidden field to do this. There are many ways to do it. But it all depends upon your approach.

Comment: You're welcome @r.d.rez. Vote up and tick if you find this answer helpful :)

Comment: Ali one more doubt i need to use this for for insert but at time its get disabled... i cant select value i added "disabled", false but i cant select value for insert case

Comment: When you are editing it, are you sending any parameter in the url? please tell me the url when you are editing it?